# Close all activities without using flag in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I wan to close all activities in a button click with out using intent flag

Scrren1 Button click ---> Screen2 Button click ----> Screen3 Button click ---> Screen1 ----> BackPressed ---> Close All activities

Any idea about how to achieve this??

Comment: Can you explain how you did this , or what you really trying for??

Comment: how you achieved `Screen3 Button click ---> Screen1 ----> BackPressed`  ?

Comment: override onBackPressed method in screen1 and use finish() inside it.

Comment: Why don't you try this using [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) ? You don't need to use intents and the 3 screens would be in the same activity.

Comment: I have edited your question to remove the tag [tag:close] because this tag is being removed from the site as discussed here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308117/1743880. If you think this tag adds value to your question, feel free to leave a comment there.